# JSFiddle code cannot run when out of JsFiddle environment

Tags: javascript, css, jsfiddle

My code for a simple anti-cyberbullying plugin works perfectly in JSFiddle, but doesn't run in my website, even when I add document.ready and use a c+p cleanser like jslint. The code does not have any warnings on JSFiddle. I have reviewed this page:([JSFiddle code not working in my own page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865241/jsfiddle-code-not-working-in-my-own-page)), but this doesn't seem to be applicable to my question. Why does the code not run in other environments when it is functional on JSFiddle?

Here's the JSFiddle: 
[The Code](https://jsfiddle.net/IrreverentSalutes/jdbma0yo/)

Here is the exact JS I am using in my website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var triggerWords = ["stupid",
    "ugly",
    "fat",
    "kill",
    "dumb",
    "idiot",
    "freak",
  ];
  $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function humhm {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {

        document.getElementById("styled").className = "mystyle";
        document.getElementById("shover").className = "mason";
        const messages = ['<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TzOBj6xt9unc8n41fMyUZ46FG4MRXBK6wkdOtzmKJPoLa9gBYNwZYQkRB8fsboqM1LHh3ahxOLOlyKsH1zG1qmGHgbS6IK-yZtv6Duo6_thwIKEVRY7BZNr2JJzAkYviyKp_q7SPWnp1"width="200px" class="floater" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">Words mean a lot. Their echoes can brighten someone\'s day. Or they can make a bad day worse. Consider the person behind the screen.', '<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TzOBj6xt9unc8n41fMyUZ46FG4MRXBK6wkdOtzmKJPoLa9gBYNwZYQkRB8fsboqM1LHh3ahxOLOlyKsH1zG1qmGHgbS6IK-yZtv6Duo6_thwIKEVRY7BZNr2JJzAkYviyKp_q7SPWnp1"width="200px" class="floater" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">Your words can be a force for happiness or dejection. Choose carefully.', 'Be mindful of your words. Would you say this in real life?', 'Consider the impact your words may have. A couple insults slung casually can be much more significant to others.', 'Words that are insignificant to you can deeply hurt another. Be empathetic. Be nice.'];
        const randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random(messages.length * 10 - 0.5));
        document.getElementById("shover").innerHTML = messages[randomIndex];
        document.getElementById("usual").className = "noshow";
        document.getElementById("trigger").className = "norm";
      }
    }
  });


});
'
```

Comment: Can you link to the site?

Comment: Shoudnt you remove the comma after sleazy?

Comment: @MichaelCoker, no, sorry. I haven't pushed it to GitHub yet.

Comment: Yes, thank you @HudsonSantos for the check.

Comment: @user12390879 curious if you are upvoting the responses in the post? you said there are no console errors. I'm assuming you loaded jquery if you aren't getting console errors, because if you didn't load jquery, that would throw an error in the console.

Comment: have you tried debugging js code using dev tools?

Comment: Yes, @Janar, but this did not return anything as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing JQuery? Commonly 'rare' errors coming from simple problems.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I recommend to you make your code more human readable taking advantage of JQuery you can replace all `document.getElementById("ID_VALUE")` for `$('#ID_VALUE')`

PD: Good luck with that anti-cyberbulling. Important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jQuery.

The JSFiddle does indeed import it.
[image]

Comment: *"There are no console errors."* if OP didn't load jquery, they would get an error "$ is not defined"